# Подогнать картинку в div по центру

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, изображения, slider

Есть бутстраповский слайдер, в котором есть картинки. При уменьшении высоты слайдера у картинок остается только верхняя часть. Как сделать так, чтобы он обрезал ее по центру?

```
    <div id="bootstrap-touch-slider" class="carousel bs-slider slide  control-round indicators-line" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-interval="5000" >

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#bootstrap-touch-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#bootstrap-touch-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#bootstrap-touch-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper For Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!-- Third Slide -->
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Slide Background -->
                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/36226/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="Bootstrap Touch Slider"  class = "slide-image"/>


                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Slide Text Layer -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код.

Comment: Добавила то что в индексе

Comment: @AlinaDyussupova Вам подошёл мой ответ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src = "img.png" class = "img-responsive">
```

Бутстрап умеет все из коробки.

Comment: применила этот класс, но он не сработал

Comment: @AlinaDyussupova, попробуйте вот этот вариант: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-responsive-carousel

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `object-fit: cover;` для `img`. В последних версиях браузеров это свойство не поддерживается только в IE. Но и для этого случая можно обойтись либо полифилом, либо обернуть в койтейнер с `position: relative`, задав абсолютное позиционирование.

Comment: к тому времени уже решила проблему тем, что просто обрезала картинку в редакторе и вставила. Но все равно спасибо, в будущем попробую воспользоваться и обязательно дам знать, как сработало